# Пересортировать json jquery результат по определенному полю

Tags: jquery, массивы, ajax, сортировка, json

Здраствуйте.
Возникла необходимость в пересортировке полученого ответа json (получаю средствами ajax jquery).
Как можно пересортировать полученый результат json по определенному полю.
Сортировка при выдаче php не предлогать. 
спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Допустим у нас есть исходный массив:

```
   var employees=[]
    employees[0]={name:"George", age:32, retiredate:"March 12, 2014"}
    employees[1]={name:"Edward", age:17, retiredate:"June 2, 2023"}
    employees[2]={name:"Christine", age:58, retiredate:"December 20, 2036"}
    employees[3]={name:"Sarah", age:62, retiredate:"April 30, 2020"}
```

Сортируем по возрасту

```
employees.sort(function(a, b){
 return a.age-b.age
})
```

Сортируем по имени

```
employees.sort(function(a, b){
 var nameA=a.name.toLowerCase(), nameB=b.name.toLowerCase()
 if (nameA < nameB) 
  return -1 
 if (nameA > nameB)
  return 1
 return 0 
})
```

Сортируем по дате

```
employees.sort(function(a, b){
 var dateA=new Date(a.retiredate), dateB=new Date(b.retiredate)
 return dateA-dateB 
})
```