# сортировать json по ключу

Tags: javascript, массивы, json, сортировка

Есть функция:

```
sort: function (jsonData) {
    return jsonData.sort(function(a,b){
        return (a < b.id) ? -1:1;
    });
},
```

Выводит ошибку : `TypeError: jsonData.sort is not a function`.
Я понимаю что функция sort не работает с объектами.
Но вот не понимаю как вернуть отсортированный массив(или объект).

Пример jsonData :

```
Object{
131:Object
132:Object
136:Object
139:Object
142:Object
143:Object
144:Object
}
```

Я хочу обратную сортировку.
Это не дубликат [Пересортировать json jquery результат по определенному полю](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/93048), там сортируется по значению, а мне нужно по ключу. Тем более там показана функция .sort, и как я сказал функция выводит ошибку. Я уже написал об этом в комментарии. Прочитайте полностью прежде чем указать что это дубликат!

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Пересортировать json jquery результат по определенному полю](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/93048/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-json-jquery-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8e)

Comment: @lexxl там сортируется по значению, а мне нужно по ключу. Тем более там показана функция .sort, и как я сказал функция выводит ошибку

Answer (score 3):

Как уже написали, сортировка объекта не имеет смысла, можно либо выбирать поля по предварительно отсортированным ключам, либо сначала разобрать поля объекта в массив, и сортировать уже его. Примерно так:

```js
var src = {
  143: {foo: 43},
  131: {foo: 31},
  132: {foo: 32},
  136: {foo: 36},
  139: {foo: 39},
  144: {foo: 44},
  142: {foo: 42}
}

// Разберем исходный объект в массив dst
var dst = [];
for (var key in src) {
  dst.push({
    key: key,
    value: src[key]
  });
}

// Теперь отсортируем массив dst
dst.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.key > b.key;
});

console.log(dst);
```

Или чуть короче с применением lodash/es6:

```
var src = {
  142: {foo: 42},
  131: {foo: 31},
  132: {foo: 32},
  136: {foo: 36},
  139: {foo: 39},
  143: {foo: 44},
  144: {foo: 44}
}

var dst = _.sortBy(_.map(src, (v, k) => ({v, k})), 'k');


console.log(dst);
```

http://jsbin.com/kikobaz/edit?js,console

Answer (score 0):

Свойства объекта не упорядочены, их невозможно сортировать.

Definition of an Object from ECMAScript 3

> **4.3.3 Object**
>
> An object is a member of the type Object. It is an unordered collection of properties each of which contains a primitive value, object, or function. A function stored in a property of an object is called a method.

ECMAScript 6

> **9.1.11 [[Enumerate]] ()**
>
> When the [[Enumerate]] internal method of O is called the following steps are taken:
>
> 1. Return an Iterator object (25.1.1.2) whose next method iterates over all the String-valued keys of enumerable properties of O. The Iterator object must inherit from %IteratorPrototype% (25.1.2). **The mechanics and order of enumerating the properties is not specified** but must conform to the rules specified below.